# Matching commas after the last semicolon on a row

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have a CSV file that has data separated by semicolons. In the last column in the file, I have a list of numbers separated by a comma. I wan't to replace these commas with a semicolon so they become their own columns.

How do I match every comma after the last semicolon on each row? I can't just replace all commas with semicolons, because some other columns in the file contain commas too.

I am trying to replace them in Notepad++.

```
189;1;data here, can contain commas;311,232,161,132,371
```

That should become

```
189;1;data here, can contain commas;311;232;161;132;371
```

Comment: What version of N++ do you have?

Comment: @Jerry 6.5.4. This shouldn't matter?

Comment: Could use a lookahead `,(?=[^;]+$)` Replace with: `;` Replace commas, not followed by semicolons to end of line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
(?:;(?!.*;)|(?!^)\G)[^,]*\K,
```

Replace with:

```
;
```

`;(?!.*;)` matches the last `;`. It's a `;`, which is not followed by another `;`.

`(?!^)\G` is used to match at the end of a previous match.

`(?:;(?!.*;)|(?!^)\G)` will mean either match the last `;`, or at the start of the previous match.

`[^,]*` will match non commas, and lastly, `\K` resets the match to allow you match only the commas.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/xN6gE7)

Note: Not all versions of Notepad++ support `\G` and `\K` (I don't remember exactly which one was implemented first though, probably `\G`).

---

The above is more... what you described. A workaround could be this:

```
,(?!.*;)
```

Match a `,` that is not followed by a `;` ahead. And replace with `;`.

Comment: @Jerry, wow, did not know about this construct, absolutely crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This regex matches a comma that does not have a semicolon between it and end of line:

```
,(?=[^;]*$)
```

If you want to delete such commas, replace matches with a blank.