# Regex to extract float from String

Tags: java, regex

I have a file which contains the following string data

```
...
v -0.570000 -0.950000 -0.100000
v 0.570000 -0.950000 -0.100000
v -0.570000 -0.760000 -0.100000
v 0.570000 -0.760000 -0.100000
...
f 34 22
f 3 35 3
f 345 22
f 55 632 76
f 55 632
....
```

From this file I want to extract all the numbers from the lines starting with 'v' and 'f'. I have written the following regex for it.

```
v(?:\s([0-9\-\.]+))+

Output:
group 1: -0.100000

f(?:\s([0-9]+))+

Output:
group 1: 22
```

But as you can see the output is only extracting the last numbers from each line, I want the output as follows:

```
Output:
group 1: -0.570000
group 2: -0.950000
group 3: -0.100000

Output:
group 1: 34
group 2: 22
```

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Just make 3 capture groups instead of repeating the first. Capture groups keep the last match.

Comment: Yes but the numbers may not be always 3 per line.

Comment: And how about splitting?

Comment: As in the above comment, if the format isn't going to change, then simply split each line and discard first "v".

Comment: Wouldn't the performance degrade if i use spliting instead of a single regex? I want to keep the time for parsing this file as minimum as possible.

Comment: Regex takes more time than splitting.

Comment: Interesting, let me try that out. But just for the knowledge, isn't this possible using only regex at all? It seems like a very basic task.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with Java's implementation, but it's possible with [PCRE flavour regex](http://regex101.com/r/iQ5pW7).

Comment: @Jerry, Nice, you couldn't explain the \G and the \K stuff to me could you? basically I don't fully understand `(?:v|(?!^)\G) \K`.

Comment: @MikeH-R I could, but I'm pretty sure it won't fit in a comment :) You could have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22835004/1578604) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22577357/1578604) maybe where I gave a description of this type of construct. Kind of recurring thing, I know and usually not easily grasped until a few tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution which I used finally, in case someone needs it.

I used two Regex instead of using string splitting as suggested in the above comments.

```
public class ObjParser {
    private static final Pattern vertexLinePattern = Pattern.compile("^v\\s(.+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    private static final Pattern faceLinePattern = Pattern.compile("^f\\s(.+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    private static final Pattern vertexValuePattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9\\-\\.]+)");
    private static final Pattern faceValuePattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)");

    private List<Float> vertices = new LinkedList<Float>();
    private List<Short> faces = new LinkedList<Short>();

    public void parseVertices(String data) {
        Matcher matcher1 = vertexLinePattern.matcher(data);
        while(matcher1.find()) {
            String line = matcher1.group(1);

            Matcher matcher2 = vertexValuePattern.matcher(line);
            while(matcher2.find()) {
                vertices.add(Float.parseFloat(matcher2.group(1)));
            }
        }
    }

    public void parseFaces(String data) {
        Matcher matcher1 = faceLinePattern.matcher(data);
        while(matcher1.find()) {
            String line = matcher1.group(1);

            Matcher matcher2 = faceValuePattern.matcher(line);
            while(matcher2.find()) {
                short no = (short)(Integer.parseInt(matcher2.group(1)) - 1); // -1 due to 1 based index in OBJ files
                faces.add(no);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Float> getVertices() {
        return vertices;
    }

    public List<Short> getFaces() {
        return faces;
    }
}
```